# Spring JDBC vs JDBC

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have been trying to use spring 3.0 SimpleJdbcTemplate and it takes 5 mins to insert 1500 records, whereas it take me a few secs. to insert using straight JDBC. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: This is not a question, nor does it provide any code for us to scrutinize, how do you expect us to help you? Please consider providing more details.

Comment: Not saying that it should be taking 5 mins to insert, but there will be a delay when you use any framework on top of "straight jdbc".  Post your queries/code so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 6):

If you are building batch consider using Spring batch - `JdbcBatchItemWriter` with proper chunk size settings, that will load these 1500 records in less than a second.

Answer (score 1):

Some things worth checking:

- The overhead might be on the transaction managed by Spring at the application level. Look what kind of transaction manager you are using (look for a bean with name `transactionManager`). If you are using JTA, that's probably where your problem is. Since it's fast with JDBC the bottleneck doesn't seem to be the db.
- Depending on how your app is using that transaction, it might be holding everything in memory before it finishes all 1500 requests and commits. Do you see a large difference in memory usage (the Spring one should be a lot higher)?
- What kind of DB connection pool are you using in either of the cases?

Quick way to profile your app:

Get the `pid - "jps -l"`

Memory: `jmap -histo PID` (check if there's some form of memory leak)

Check what's going on under the hood: `jstack PID` (look for slow or recursive method calls)

Answer (score -2):

How about using

```
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(new String[]{sql});
```